# Яндекс-Карты: адрес центра карты

Tags: яндекс-карты

В документации есть пример получения координат центра карты, например можно делать так:

```
map.action.events.add('tickcomplete', function (e) {
          const tick = e.get('tick');
          const coords = (map.options
              .get('projection')
              .fromGlobalPixels(tick.globalPixelCenter, tick.zoom));
```

Можно ли подобным образом получить адрес центра карты?

Ещё вопрос - не нашёл в документации описания fromGlobalPixels и globalPixelCenter, подскажите ссылочку, если описание есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить центр карты можно с помощью метода getCenter

```
map.getCenter()
```

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__getCenter

Методы fromGlobalPixels и globalPixelCenter можно увидеть тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/projection.wgs84Mercator-docpage/

Comment: Спасибо, getCenter() удобнее. Основной вопрос был как получить адрес центра карты, или простой метод получения адреса по координатам. Можете подсказать?

Comment: пропустил) https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/reverse_geocode вот тут можно посмотреть на геокодирование и там прям центр карты используется. А вот тут на контрол который отображает адрес в центре карты https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control

Comment: Не могу понять. Можете привести пример, как с помощью геокоординат получить адрес в виде строки, или объект, из которого эту строку можно извлечь?

Comment: ymaps.geocode(myMap.getCenter()).then(function (res) {console.log(res.geoObjects.get(0).getAddressLine());}); Почитать о запросе можно тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geocode-docpage/ , а об ответе тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeocodeResult-docpage/